# R - Exclude participants based on the condition (more than 10% of their response--variable:latency-- is less than 300ms)

Tags: r, dataframe, filter, subset

I am trying to exclude data(participants) who fall into exclusion criteria: exclude those who have more than 10% of their responses as less than 300ms.

So just make it more understandable, here is an example (fake) of the data (lets say data name is MyData):

```
structure(list(ID = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
), .Label = c("rladb11", "rladb7"), class = "factor"), blocknum = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L), latency = c(322L, 277L, 243L, 188L, 
642L, 155L, 122L, 233L, 280L, 142L, 834L, 243L, 332L, 243L, 275L, 
432L, 524L, 534L, 143L, 533L, 242L, 234L, 523L, 142L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-24L))
```

So we have variables -- ID, Block(1-4), latency.
The latency measured the time they took until they responded correctly.

What I need to do is exclude participants (ID) whose responses were too fast that we think they didn't pay attention. So the criterion for this is if there were more than **10% of their responses** during **block 2, 3** that were **less than 300ms**, they will be excluded.

However the provided data here is raw (fake) data. Our main data --summarized-- is separate. So we'd need to have a list of those excluded.

How can I get the list of those participants ID who didn't meet the criteria?

So with this data set, we'd want to see the result,

```
rladb7
```

--------(old)datailed questions below------------

I was trying to do this by using subset function

and then finally print if latencyPercent is more than 10%.

And then do this same thing for all 100~ participants to find out those who did too fast.

but the problems are:

1. It is too much job --not efficient-- just to subset all the 100~ participants' data one by one to do this exclusion method.
2. I should not count their response on block 1, 4 (just need those in block 2,3)

I am very new to R programming so any help will be so much helpful and appreciated..!! Does anyone have a good suggestion on how to effectively exclude those?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: @RonakShah I can't provide the real data since that will be violation of privacy and confidentiality... Everything is pretty vague at this moment since I do not know much about functions out there. That's why I was explaining the concepts and giving an "example" and hoping for any suggestions.. So, my simple question would be (maybe this would have been a better and simple question) how can I exclude the participants/ID (each throughout multiple rows) who didn't meet the criteria (more than 10% responses in block 2,3,4 are <300)

Comment: well, the "example" you shared should be shared using `dput` and not as an image as it is explained in the link which I posted in my first comment. We need data to test our solutions. We can't use image to test that.

Comment: I see!! I just added a data example using dput!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can find the ratio of `latency` which is less than 300 and where `blocknum` is either `2:3` for each `ID` and keep only those ID's where the ratio is greater than 10%.

```
library(dplyr)

Mydata %>%
   group_by(ID) %>%
   filter(mean(latency < 300 & blocknum %in% 2:3) > 0.1)


#    ID     blocknum latency
#   <fct>     <int>   <int>
# 1 rladb7        1     322
# 2 rladb7        2     277
# 3 rladb7        2     243
# 4 rladb7        2     188
# 5 rladb7        2     642
# 6 rladb7        2     155
# 7 rladb7        3     122
# 8 rladb7        3     233
# 9 rladb7        3     280
#10 rladb7        3     142
#11 rladb7        3     834
#12 rladb7        4     134
```

---

to get only the `ID`, we can `pull` :

```
Mydata %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(mean(latency < 300 & blocknum %in% 2:3) > 0.1) %>% 
  distinct(ID) 

#    ID    
#  <fct> 
#1 rladb7
```

Comment: Thanks so much! Unfortunately, the second one is not working. I have uploaded my fake dataset using dput as you recommended, and edited the question to be clearer!

Comment: Sorry my wasn't saved. but now they are there. I have added my fake data using dput. How can I get the list of the participants' ID who didn't meet the criteria? Also, we only need to check the responses rate (<300ms) in response 2,3 (1,4 is not counted since they are different measures). Thanks!

Comment: @JJJJJJJ Check my updated answer. Is this what you want?

Comment: Thanks Ronak. I m not sure why your coding listed all the responses from one participant. I'd only want to see "rladb7" (who'd be the one who didn't meet the criteria, which is more than 10% of his/her responses during block# 2, 3 were <300ms .

Comment: @JJJJJJJ You can add `distinct`. See updated answer.